# How to match harmonica impedance to a tube amp to eliminate feedback

Tags: amplifier, feedback, attenuator, tube

What circuits eliminate feedback between hi z harmonica mics and high gain guitar tube amps?

Do FET circuits work? I have used tube bases attenuators in the past for 50 watt amps, but they reduce the volume too much  for 25 watt tube amps.

I currently have a 25 watt tube amp I'm trying to use a hi z bullet mic with. It makes good tone, but feeds back once volume  gets in the sweet “tone” spot harmonics wise

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to achieve. Not clear what "hi z harmonica mics" or "high gain amp" are. Show us the schematics with as much detail as possible. Explain why the impedance needs to be matched.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is electronic and not acoustic?  If the feedback is from the monitor to the mic, via the air, then you're going to fix that with basic sound setup -- not electronically.

Answer (score 1):

You seemingly want certain distorted sound and reach it in the same way as rock guitarists - by cranking the gain up until the amp distorts enough. Unfortunately the feedback caused by high gain with acoustic mic easily makes the system to squeal. The hands around the mic +using some high midrange peaking mic (possibly designed originally to increase the clarity of human voice) make things worse. Things become even worse if high onstage sound level force the harmonica player to turn his amp or monitor speaker louder just to be able to hear what he plays.

Modern DSP has given automatic feedback suppressors which really can detect starting squeal and equalize the peaking frequency gain down to a safe level. A little older tricks are

- to have a normal parametric or terse equalizer which attenuates the most easily squealing frequency range
- to use a noise gate which automatically shuts the mic totally in silent places and
- a few Hz pitch shift which makes feedback to have a little wrong frequency for fast buildup

I recommend lower onstage sound levels. A loud amp for right sound can be enclosed to isolation box or use attenuated speaker. Simply moving it further also reduces feedback, but something extra may be needed to let the player hear himself. In-ear monitor can keep excessive noise out and make the wanted sound well hearable for the player. I have met singers who have purchased a personal earplug monitor system which actually outputs only their own voice and attenuate everything else purely mechanically (=very small holes for external sound)

Answer (score 1):

Circuits do not cause acoustic feedback.  The feedback comes from the physical locations of the mic and the speakers, and the phase relationship through the amplifier.

The easiest thing to try is to move the mic stand, speakers, or both.  Next up, reverse the speaker wire connections.  This changes the overall loop (mic > amp > speaker > air > mic) relationship by shifting the signal by 180 degrees.

Electronically, you can insert a multi-band graphics equalizer between the preamp and power amp stages, and decrease the signal amplitude in a narrow frequency band around the feedback frequency.

I wouldn't be surprised if someone makes a feedback eliminator gadget that is a very narrow band, tunable band-reject filter to suck out the feedback frequency with minimal effect on the rest of the signal spectrum.  Wouldn't be hard to build, maybe 2 opamps as a twin-T filter and output driver, and a couple of batteries.